# Как вы интерпретируете правило SRP (Единственная обязанность класса)?

Tags: ооп, solid

Если подойти формально к этому вопросу, то получается, что каждый метод (функция) это отдельный класс. Но это большая ошибка так делать. Как вы интерпретируете эту рекомендацию?

P.S. я напрашиваюсь на исчерпывающий ответ, а не копипасту с википедии.

Comment: Почему каждый метод — это отдельный класс? Внутренние (приватные) методы часто вовсе не имеют семантики.

Comment: Имеется ввиду публичные.

Comment: @АлексейМальченко если публичные методы семантически связаны между собой, то это нормально.  Тут тогда скорее другой вопрос: насколько мелко надо разделять обязанности класса и дробить его. Из крайности в крайности впадать не надо

Answer (score 0):

Например, если класс должен работать со строками, то у него и должны быть только свойства и методы для работы со строками: возврат размера строки, добавление к строке, получение символа по индексу и т.п.

Есть к примеру `base64`, это строка, но тот гипотетический класс не должен уметь кодировать и раскодировать `base64`, для этого должен быть создан отдельный класс `Base64`

Comment: **Кодирование** и **раскодирование** Base64 это два разных вида деятельности, почему бы не разнести их по двум классам? Ну, это SRP, все дела </сарказм>

Comment: Вот кстати дельный комментарий. Делить или не делить? Вдруг мне РП дядя Вася через пол года скажет: "А давай-ка кодировать в base64, а раскодировать в hex", а у нас опа и уже почти все готово для этого!  
А ведь дядя Вася может и не попросить через пол года сделать это, и тогда все зря. Вектор изменений не очевиден.

Comment: @АлексейМальченко, попрошу без фанатизма :) Создавать лишние сущности явно не нужно -- код становится сложнее, а ООП должен был упрощать код, а не усложнять. Для работы с Base64 заводится одна сущность -- позволяющая из байтового массива кодировать в строку base64, и обратное действие. Для Hex тоже свой класс для кодирования/раскодирования. Также как и для классов криптографии.

Comment: Видел я солянку классов для скачивания страницы по Url. Класс для Url. Класс для соединения по Url. Класс-фабрика для классов-потоков. У класса для соединения по Url запрашивается поток, который в цикле мурыжится, возвращаются байтики, который добавляются в еще один класс потока.

Черт! Как это дико неудобно! Как много сущностей!

В другой библиотеке я просто у класса вызываю метод get, передаю ему в строке url и получаю объект Response, который может дать байтовый массив страницы, или уже в виде строки (utf-8), и многое другое: url, заголовки, куки и прочее. Это просто и понятно.

Comment: Интерфейс класса нужно разрабатывать с точки зрения клиента этого класса (Кто его будет юзать). Я всегда могу найти что-то, что можно вынести. А надо-ли? Если больше нигде юзаться не будет, то что я мог бы вынести.

Comment: @gil9red фанатизм фанатизмом, но вопрос как раз в том, "где грань".